# Wrong errors if using Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

We are obfuscating our app using proguard. In our app, we're using retrofit, ok http, RxJava. Despite of adding all required lines in proguard rule file, app is behaving weirdly. Its showing dialogues with error that are supposed to be shown when server error comes but server response is correct. In another case, its not displaying error message that we receive from server when error comes. These are the lines we are adding:

```
-dontwarn com.google.errorprone.annotations.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
```

Thanks

Comment: When you build your app in debug mode, everything is ok? I mean without obfuscating.

Comment: You need to use `keep` NOT `-dontwarn`

Comment: @salman its fine without obfuscation

Comment: @Koustuv Even if we use these lines, wrong responses are still the same: 
     -keep class com.squareup.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}

-keep interface retrofit.** { *;}
-keep interface com.squareup.** { *; }

Comment: ... definition of `Wrong errors` (and `Correct errors` as well)?

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your progaurd:

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
```